# Create a Custom global Nav for Sharepoint 2007 using a usercontrol

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

We have requirement of developing a custom Global Nav for Sharepoint 2007/MOSS.
AS the Nav might include images like http://www.progressive.com/.
We are planning for doing this using a usercontrol.
Need some light on this.

Thanks
Rama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455814/custom-sharepoint-navigation-linking-to-list-views/2458063#2458063) provides a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2006/12/02/customizing-the-wss-3-0-moss-2007-menu-control-mossmenu-source-code-released.aspx) to the source code to create your won navigation control. You can then render jQuery script to get whatever results you require.